# c# - Interior.Color not working

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, cell, cells

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Code

```
oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.Name = "Data";
oSheet.Cells[1, 1].Interior.Color = 4;
```

My goal to get the cell value and need to set Background color to color index 4.

Example.

If cell[5,2] contain Text as "NO", need to set  set Background color to color.
 index 4.

But I am getting error as

> does not contain a definition for 'Interior' and no extension method 'Interior' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself but if you want to use `Color` than you have to use RGB values. But be carefull since B and R are switched, so you have to use B G R to set your `Color`.

If you want to use your color index 4 then use `ColorIndex` instead.

```
oSheet.Cells[1, 1].Interior.ColorIndex = 4;
```

Comment: `.Interior.ColorIndex` isn't found in my assembly is it saying... Any idea?